# get the true type prototype vs constructor?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to see the real type of  `[]` .

I always thought that i can use the apply method or the constructor .

so i tried :

`[].constructor` ->(showed me) `function Array() { [native code] }`

and

`[].constructor.constructor` ->(showed me)  `function Function() { [native code] }`

and

`Object.prototype.toString.apply([])` ->(showed me)  `"[object Array]"`

---

questions

1) Whom to believe ?

2)why line 2 is different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1) Whom to believe ?*

All of them. They're all correct

> *2) why line 2 is different ?*

Because `[].constructor` is a function, and the `.constructor` of a function is the `Function` constructor.

The last line is giving you the internal *[[Class]]* property of the object. It is only accessible by setting the object as the context of the generic `toString()` method, which is only available on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: This answer would be good if you also added which one to use to figure out the "type".

Comment: why this `Function` is with capital F ?

Comment: @JakubHampl: That's a matter of opinion and circumstance. Either the first or third could be used depending on the situation.

Comment: @user1175687: Because I'm referring to the `Function` constructor, as in `window.Function`. You can do `var f = new Function('alert("hi");'); f();` ...just like you can do `var a = new Array(); a.push("hi");`